# Angular - communication from child-component to parent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I don't get i, how to communicate between components and services..  :(
I have read and tried a lot about even if some examples somehow work, I do not understand why (?)

what I want to achieve:
I have one parent and two child-components:

- dashboard

  - toolbar
  - graph

in the toolbar-component I have a searchfield, which gets it's result from a external source  (works via service)..  when the result arrives, I need to trigger the updateGraph()-Method in the graph-component

toolbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { WebsocketsService } from '../../../services/websockets/websockets.service';
import { DataService } from '../../../services/data/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss'],
  providers: [WebsocketsService, DataService]
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() newGraphData: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  searchField: FormControl;
  search: string;

  private isNewGraph = false;

  constructor(private _websocketsService: WebsocketsService, private _dataService: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchField = new FormControl();
    this.searchField.valueChanges
        .subscribe(term => {
          this.search = term;
        });    
  }

  private applySearch() {
    const res = this._websocketsService.sendQuery(this.search);
    this._dataService.setGraphData(res);
    this.newGraphData.emit(true);

    this.search = '';
    this.searchField.reset();
  }
}
```

graph-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { HttpService } from '../../../services/http/http.service';
import { DataService } from '../../../services/data/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'graph',
  templateUrl: './graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph.component.scss'],
  providers: [HttpService, DataService]
})
export class GraphComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor( private _httpService: HttpService, private _dataService: DataService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public renderResult() {   
     console.log( this._dataService.getGraphData() );     
  }
}
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {  

  private graphData: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  public setGraphData(data) {
    this.graphData.next( data );
  }

  public getGraphData() {
    return this.graphData;
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

I simply want ´renderResult()´to be executed after the searchresult has been written to ´graphData´. please help i am confused.

Comment: What are you passing to the `newGraphData` output?

Comment: This question is asked quite often, and is well explained on the official website of Angular https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @DanielB ..nothing at the moment.. it was just a try, when I tried&errored

Comment: @Ploppy .. yes, this is one of the explanations I did read about a hundred times now.. i simply don't get it ..   WHAT do I have to subscribe to be able to trigger the ´renderResult()´-method when ´graphData´ is beeing set/updated

Comment: What you describe in the question details doesn't match with the question itself.

Comment: You pass the function you want to execute on the `.emit()` call to the the `@Output`. It's as simple as that! If you don't pass any function to it, nothing will fire!

Comment: @Daniel B .. I dont understand.. how can I pass the function `renderResult` to ´emit()´ when `renderResult` is a function of a different component? ..

Comment: You say you've read the documentation for `@Output` but your missing the most fundamental point. You have your component `<toolbar>` and you pass a function to the `@Output` just like `<toolbar (newGraphData)="functionToRunOnEmit($event)")>`. The `functionToRunOnEmit` is defined in your parent component, and will be triggered when you `emit()` in your child component.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want communication between components and service.

A[component] (make a information) -----(notification)-----> B[service] ----(send)----> C[component] (consume the information)

It's correct? Let's go.

You need create a subscription of graphData(data.service.ts) in GraphComponent.

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class GraphComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

constructor( private _httpService: HttpService, private _dataService: DataService ) {
  }

private subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.subscription = this._dataService.getGraphData().asObservable().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
     });

  }
}
```

Look here to help you. 
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: `this._dataService.getGraphData().asObservable().subscribe((data)`.. throws an error, that `asObservable()` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, I think you need to subscribe to the `getGraphData` subject, something like this (NOT RECOMMENDED):

```
public renderResult() {   
   this._dataService.getGraphData().subscribe(d => {
    console.log(d)
   });
}
```

It is not recommended as per the lead of RxJS says: https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93

Better answer, create an `observable` in your `service` and subscribe to that instead.

data.service.ts

```
graphObservable = this.graphData.asObservable();
```

graph-component.ts

```
public renderResult() {   
  this._dataService.graphObservable().subscribe(d => {
    console.log(d)
  });
}
```